# I Update Visual Studio to 17.6.5 and After publish the website no working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I was working in visual studio 2022 V 17.5.1 and every thing go fine
after  i update to 17.6.5
i get Error
invalidoperationexception the view 'index' was not found

and i solve this error  by
1- add this package
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
2- then change
services.AddControllersWithViews() to services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().

but when I publish the website to IIS not working
and i don't get any error just
The website cannot display the page   HTTP 500

how i can solve this issue

and I try to rollback the update of visual studio to 17.5.1
and Evey thing work fine

but VS 17.6.5 not working after publish  in IIS

Comment: Have you checked that, your server has the required packages installed? What happens, if you run the published file in local IIS environment, I mean the machine you have installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package?

Comment: the Visual studio and IIS are in the same server 
so i install the package in that server

Comment: Have you checked the server stack trace or log regarding the 500 error details?

Comment: Yes  i see this error 
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer
EventId: 2
SpanId: c6153d9b71687d52
TraceId: 9f79dfae01aef1b379474aa65fd76d1f
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 80000094-0006-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /hr

Connection ID "18374686507052040339", Request ID "80000094-0006-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Comment: When you use runtime compilation, the .cshtml files must be included in the published website, because the Razor compiler needs to find them to compile them at first run. You can also use build-time compilation, which will compile the views into DLLs that will be deployed with your website.

Runtime compilation is most valuable in development settings, while build-time compilation is the preferred method for compiling Razor files in production environments. It provides optimal performance, security, and dependability.

Comment: thanks Jeno Laszlo to help me 
i don't understand can give me an example please